# How to get EMR cluster information from slave machine (task instance group)

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-ec2, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I have to get information about EMR cluster from task instance group (slave) instances.

**My current approach-**

For that, I got private ip address from slave instance, and over that I used given command -

`aws ec2 describe-instances --region us-west-2 --filters "Name=private-ip-address,Values=172.30.5.247" | jq '.Reservations'[0] | jq '.Instances'[0] | jq '.Tags'`

This way, we can get cluster-id of EMR. But, this may lead to AWS throttling issue. So, I am guessing, definitely all slave machines should have its EMR cluster information locally.

If there is such information present, then share the file name.
If you have other better way to retrieve this information, please suggest that.

Comment: /mnt/var/lib/info contains all information regarding EMR cluster.